# To upload a file to amazon s3 using lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I used this python code to upload file to s3 bucket using lambda. Getting an error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \\UXXXXXXXX escape (lambda_function.py, line 10)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 10\n        file_name= \"C:\\Users\\smanthriprag\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\s.jpeg\"\n"
  ]
}
```

```py
import json
import boto3


from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def lambda_handler(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    
    file_name= "C:\Users\smanthriprag\Pictures\Screenshots\s.jpeg"
    bucket= "serverlesswebapp0406"

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
        print('Step 3: upload done')
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True['response']
```

Comment: There are several errors in your program including: Incorrect handler (see below), the `file_name` being in Windows format and referring to a non-existent file, and `True['response']` (which doesn't make sense).

Comment: How is this Lambda function being invoked?

Comment: Your code does not make much sense: the handler is incorrectly defined, a \ needs to be escaped. But most importantly: you cannot reference a file that is stored on your computer for the user smanthriprag in a lambda function, that is not how *anything* works.

Comment: I am very new to AWS. Can you tell me how can I upload a file to s3 bucket using lambda?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/

Comment: I referred from this website - https://www.stackery.io/blog/python-for-serverless/

Answer (score 2):

An AWS Lambda function written in Python should use the following handler:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
```

If information is being passed into the Lambda function, it will be made available via the `event`. The contents of `event` depends upon how the Lambda function is triggered (eg triggered by S3, triggered by SQS, or run via an `Invoke()` command).

Your program has an incorrect definition for the handler function.

See: [Lambda function handler in Python - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html)

Comment: While this is true, the actual error OP receives is because `\U` `\s` `\P` or `\S` are not valid escape sequences.